# Display text in gui from matlab code

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text

I have matlab code (.m file) that it's output is a text displayed using

```
disp('');
```

I want to run this code and display the output text in gui text box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you normally display text like this:

```
disp('Hello world')
```

which would display "Hello world" at the MATLAB command line. To display the same thing on a GUI, assuming you have a `uicontrol` of type `text` you would do something like:

```
h = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Hello world');
```

If you have a (string) variable with the text inside it, you can also change the `String` property of the `uicontrol` once it's created if you have access to its handle, e.g.

```
my_str = 'Hello world';
set(h,'String',my_str);
```

Read the doc for more details. [GUI Building Basics](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/gui-building-basics.html) is a good place to start.